# No sound when playing a music or a video but notification sound effects work normally

Tags: sound, video, alsa, notification

Whether I try to get the sound via my speakers or my headphones, videos played on firefox, or movies that are being played on any other software does not give any sound but notification sounds of ubuntu such as USB plug-in sound works normally.

I tried to reinstall -alsa stuff but didn't give a solution. What should I do?

I uploaded a video on youtube to show my problem : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dg3pxC9XLDM

Answer (score 0):

Try going into your sound settings and selecting a different output method.
See screenshot below:

[image: Ubuntu Sound settings]

If I choose "Digital Outout (S/PDIF)" as my output, there is no sound. But if I choose "Speakers" sound works correctly.

Comment: Well, I don't even have the option "Digital Outout (S/PDIF)" as my output. My speakers are the only output option that I can pick :/

Comment: here is a video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dg3pxC9XLDM